# Python code translation to JVM

Tags: java, python, android, jvm, dalvik

Is there such a thing as a "translator" (for lack of a better word in my mind now) that translates Python code directly to JVM / Dalvik bytecode?

Would be great for writing Android applications in Python!

**NOTE**: I know about the scripting capabilities of the Android platform but I am looking for something that would generate a '.apk' without having to install the 'scripting' package... annoying for end-users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo) you can go to Java bytecode using [`jythonc`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-25-sect-3.html).  Though I'm not sure how well that would work with the Dalvik format's subtle differences.

**edit**: apparently there was a [`jythonroid`](http://code.google.com/p/jythonroid/) project which aims to do exactly what you want, but they abandoned it in favor of SL4A

Answer (score 3):

[try jython](http://www.jython.org/) - python implementatjon for the jvm

Answer (score 3):

For running python code on a JVM, check out [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)

As far as dalvik, I'm not aware of any way to convert python to dalvik. Although there is the [Android Scripting Enviornment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) which allows you to run several scripting languages in android.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wikipedia entryon Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) and [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683777/python-code-translation-to-jvm/4683791#4683791) answer, I think you may try compile into Java bytecode using jythonc and then use the dx tool to convert it to .dex files.

From the wikipadia:

> *A tool called dx is used to convert some (but not all) Java .class files into the .dex format.*

Let us know if this works.